# Need to redirect (301) just the exact URL : www.abc.com/wholesale but it's rewriting everything with "wholesale"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need to redirect the following URL (and NOTHING with additional URL paths after the wholesale) :

**www.jedzebel.com/wholesale** (or jedzebel.com/wholesale)

to the following :

**www.jedzebel.com/wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html**

Unfortunately, I have a folder called wholesale already and when a standard 301 redirect is in place the mod_rewrite rules are causing the all URL's with wholesale in the path to rewrite incorrectly.

I tried the following in both RedirectMatch and Redirect in .htaccess after the Joomla rewrite rules but I must have something wrong  :

```
RedirectMatch (.*)/wholesale?$ http://www.jedzebel.com/wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 ^wholesale?$ http://www.jedzebel.com/wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html
```

Any ideas ?  I need to ONLY rewrite exactly www.jedzebel.com/wholesale ...

Comment: `...e?$`? Why are you making the `e` optional?

Comment: I didn't mean to ... can you suggest what I really want ? :-)

Comment: `?` in regexe makes the previous "thing" optional. it's "0 or 1 of the previous things", so you're making the `e` optional

Comment: Maybe use ^wholesale/?$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make trailing slash optional in your rule.

You can try this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wholesale/?$ /wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html
```

**Alternative:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wholesale/?$ /wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This caused a homepage 500 server error ... I had the issue with everything I've tried since using regex ...

Comment: Thought the following worked because the URL rewrite issue is fixed but it doesn't work for the intended purpose originally ... at least it doesn't kill the other URL's ...

Comment: What is the URL that doesn't redirect. `/` is probably needed after `^`

Comment: www.jedzebel.com/wholesale is not redirecting ... maybe you're right but the / seemed to cause the 500 error

Comment: I have tested this rule before posting. For 500 I suggested that you need to check error.log. Can you try updated answer (alternative).

Comment: Ok, you were right !  Thanks so much ... the server error must have been a coincidence in timing.  The apache logs show no 500 errors AND it appears to be working in all respects.  So for others who want to use this format :  RedirectMatch 301 ^/wholesale/?$ /wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html  also this  
RedirectMatch 301 ^/WHOLESALE/?$ /wholesale-info/wholesale-information.html